Why double pointer has a type
Why does a double pointer such as char **ptr; have a type? It just stores an address of memory, which has a fixed size so it doesn't change from type to another, so why do not all types have the same double pointer?
So what will happen if we assign a double pointer to another single pointer's type?

a double pointer is a pointer that points to a pointer which points to an object.  That is distinct from a single pointer that points to a object.  Different semantics means different types.

Every C++ Object ( not to be confused with Object Orientated ) has a type. A double pointer has a type of "pointer to pointer" and a single pointer has a type of "pointer to value".  "...So what will happen if we assign a double pointer to another single pointer's type..." - compilation error as the types are not the same and there is no conversion sequence.  For clarity please post a [mcve].

The compiler wouldn't know if a double pointer's target is the right type (of pointer).

You are almost right ;-). On "typical" implementations, pointers to data types have the same size; alas, there is no guarantee. Originally, in early C, pointers were indeed basically treated as integers. It is with larger programs that the need evolved to have a stricter type system (for example, C++'s is stricter than C's) so that the programmer's intentions are documented immediately in code, and the compiler has a chance to verify that the program realizes the intentions and not something else.

If you are asking why the language was designed this way, hard-typed ( back in the 1980s based on C 1970s ) this will probably be Opinion Based and off-topic for SO.

And re "what will happen if we access memory through a wrongly typed pointer": Technically, it is undefined behavior, and your program or machine may crash. Realistically, without aggressive optimization, the code will simply treat the byte pattern that happens to reside in the given memory as the suggested type. With aggressive optimization, branches of if clauses may be skipped surprisingly, memory may not be reloaded/rewritten etc.

By "double pointer" do you mean double* p; or do you mean void** p;?

Type-safe languages make you the programmer a bit safer from stupid mistakes.  C and C++ allow quite a bit of dangerous programming already eg c-style casts, reinterpret_cast.  The language is trying to protect you from yourself.

Because manually managing double pointers is just asking for a lot of bugs. Also there is almost NO place for void* in C++. It seems someone is trying to teach you C not C++.  For arrays C++ has std::array, std::vector (and you can nest them). One of the idioms of current C++ is : No raw pointer arithmetic, No owning raw pointers. So if you're new to C++ just stay away from them for a while.

I mean any ** pointer not a pointer of type double

There is a universal double pointer. Its type is void **. You can do with it everything you can do with all the conventionally typed double pointers. You can pretend that int ** and double ** and everything else just do not exist, and do everything with void **. Try it for a couple of month, then tell us whether you liked the experience. (Caveat, this assumes that all pointers have the same size, representation and alignment; this is true for most conventional implementations, but the standards do not mandate it).

@n.m.couldbeanAI Of course any_type_or_void ** is an object pointer. "all pointers have the same size," --> I want to add: still common enough that pointers to objects have a different size than function pointers.

I definitely remember the time I once chased down a difficult bug that involved a pointer-to-data in a void* and a pointer-to-pointer-to-data in a void* that were passed into the same code which was actually only capable of handling one of those two scenarios. Type-safety helps programmers write correct programs.

See dupe: Why is the data type needed in pointer declarations? and Why do you have to specify a type for pointers?


Why double pointer has a type

Every object (variable) needs to have a type since that determines its size and how its used. That includes pointers and double-pointers.

address of memory has a fixed size

Not so. Pointers of different types can have different sizes.

so why not all types have the same double pointer?

I believe you are asking why all double pointers don't all have the same type. Because 1) nothing would know to what they point (i.e. the type of *p), and even if they did, 2) nothing would know to what the pointed pointers point (i.e. the type of **p). This brings us back to the first question.

I suppose the OP refers to the double in double* when they ask "why does a pointer have a type". And of course you can have void pointers which have "no type" in that sense, and you can of course imagine a language where all pointers are just void and the actual type after dereferencing is deduced from context or must be given, e.g. void *p; int i; p = &i; *p = 3; is a totally legit language design. it is just not very safe. In particular, typically sizeof(T1*) == sizeof(T2*) for any PODs, so the size argument does not hold for most architectures.

@Peter - Reinstate Monica, To me, a double pointer is Type**. If they're asking why a double* has a type, then just ignore the "2)" part.

@Peter - Reinstate Monica, I interpret such question in the framework of the language at hand. /// Note that it's perfectly acceptable to assign a float to an int in C, so *p = 3.3; would fail miserably in your hypothesized language.  And there's the whole question of how would *p + 1 work. I'm guessing that's what you mean by "not very safe" :)

@Peter - Reinstate Monica, The OP has clarified they are talking about Type**

Oh, I see. That makes it indeed very likely that they have the same size independent of the eventual object type. And, of course, my "you could as well only have void pointers" is independent of the pointer type (that's the whole point), including pointers to pointers.

@Peter - Reinstate Monica, Re "That makes it indeed very likely", It doesn't change the likelyhood. /// void ** can be hard to use. int ip = ...; void *vp = ip; f( &vp ); ip = vp; ... must be used instead of int ip = ...; f( &ip ); ... given void f( void ** );. Maybe that's the basis of the question?

Pointers-to-pointers are not special in this regard. The answer for them is the same as for any other pointers:

It tells the compiler how to interpret the pointed value, when you dereference the pointer.
(When you do **p, how many bytes should we read/write from the address stored at *p? And how should those bytes be interpreted?)

It adds some type safety - you can't convert to and from a pointer to a different type without a cast.



When you say double pointer I'm assuming you mean like this:
int var = 10;
int* pointer_to_var = &var;
int** pointer_to_pointer_to_var = &pointer_to_var;

And you're wondering why pointer_to_pointer_to_var has a type since it's just pointing to a memory address?
The main reason is that it's just more useful that way and can cause bugs on your side if you didn't know the underlying type of what's being pointed to.
While you can represent the above example as a void pointer (void*), it's generally better to just stick with int**. For example, if I want to get the original value of my_variable, if it was a void pointer how would you or the compiler know what the resulting type would be?
(**pointer_to_pointer_to_var) // We know this is an 'int'

(**some_void_pointer) // What would the type be? How would the compiler know if it's an int, bool, etc...?

In addition, if for whatever reason you want to increment the underlying pointer, it's as easy as doing this:
(*pointer_to_pointer_to_var) += 1;

And it'll automatically increment the address by 4 bytes because the compiler knows an int is 4 bytes (assuming sizeof(int) = 4) - this is useful for arrays for example.
In both the above cases you're just having to do extra work if you were to use void* pointers that have no type. You'd have to first cast it to the proper pointer type and then you can use it.
All that extra brainpower and work can be saved if you just remember what type the pointer to the pointer is pointing to.


Why does a double pointer such as char **ptr; have a type? It just stores an address of memory, which has a fixed size so it doesn't change from type to another, so why do not all types have the same double pointer?

I take you to be asking about the "char" part of char **.  That is, why is there not a single type pointer_to_pointer for all double pointers?
There is a variety of reasons, but the common denominator is that it matters what type of pointer the double pointer points to. For instance:

we need to know the type of the object obtained by doubly dereferencing the the double pointer.  In C, that's conveyed only by the double-pointer type, not by the pointer value to which it points.

it is not necessarily the case that different pointer types have the same size or representation.  Historically, there have been C implementations that offered pointers of different sizes, especially, but not limited to, the size of function pointers differing from the size of object pointers.

it is more logically consistent to have distinct double pointer types. Given any type, we can derive a pointer type from it, and pointer types derived from different base types are different.  But pointer types are types, so pointer derivation applies to them, too.

in a similar vein, double pointers are fundamentally single pointers (to a pointer type).  It's not clear, then, why they shouldn't be different from each other, when single-pointer types with different referenced types are different from each other.  All the same considerations apply.



So what will happen if we assign a double pointer to another single pointer's type?

The language specifications do not define behavior for assigning a value of one pointer type to a pointer type whose referenced type is not compatible (as the spec defines that), unless one of the referenced types is void. This is a language constraint, so conforming compilers will emit a diagnostic if it is violated.  The specs do allow conversions, however, via explicit cast, among pointers to different object types, or between pointers to different function types.  Having performed such a conversion, it is not remarkable to store the result in a variable having the same type as the converted result.
For most such cases, the specs do not define the behavior of accessing the referenced object or calling the referenced function via such a converted pointer.  Among the main things you can definedly do with such a pointer are

convert it back to its original type -- with the result required to compare equal to the original (pointer) value

convert it to an integer type

compare it for equality with another pointer to the same (new) type, with a pointer to void, or with a null pointer constant


